# Pass id and values of combo both to controller from ExtJS

Tags: extjs4

I wanted to Pass both id and value of combo selected both to controller from ExtJS. In my case, id is country code and value is country name. Here for Combo I am not using var.
For ex:

```
{   
                            xtype: 'combo',
                            id: 'ADDRESS_COUNTRY_NAME',
                            name: 'ADDRESS_COUNTRY_NAME',     
                            fieldLabel: 'Country',
                            width: 300,
                            displayField: 'name',
                            store: addrcountriesStore,
                            queryMode: 'local',
                            listConfig: {
                                getInnerTpl: function() {
                                    return '<div data-qtip="{name}">{name}</div>';
                                }
                            }}
 var addrcountriesStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'AddrCountry',
    data: addrcountries
});

var addrcountries = [
    {"id":"US","name":"United States"},
    {"id":"UK","name":"United Kingdom"},
    {"id":"AU","name":"Australia"}
];

Ext.define('AddrCountry', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {type: 'string', name: 'id'},
        {type: 'string', name: 'name'}
    ]
});
```

By default country name is going during form post. I need to send corresponding country code as well. Could anybody please help?

Answer (score 0):

Kiran is on the right track. once you get the two variables you need to set a hidden field with one of them (countryID).  However it seems wrong to store both on the server - just saying.